# Multithreaded X11 application and OpenGL

Tags: multithreading, opengl, thread-safety, x11

I'm trying to create a multithreaded opengl application with libx11 - with one separate thread per window, and one manager thread.

I have an event loop in the manager thread:

```
while(true)
  while(XQLength(mPlatformData->display)){
    XNextEvent(mPlatformData->display, &event);
    std::cout << "event" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This is a great event loop for single threaded applications, but with this multithreaded setup strange things happen.

When I'm creating a window, I need to disable the event queue, or GLXMakeCurrent will just hang - my entire thread stops, and does nothing.

I can't find much information about multithreaded X11 applications on the net, should I handle my events differently?

Comment: I guess X11 and OpenGL are thread unsafe.

Comment: GL is thread safe if I use one context / thread. And according to X11 documentation, it should be safe if I call XInitThreads() first, what I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that Xlib has several unfixable runtime issues that manifest in concurent access situations. I'm guessing you're running into exactly one of those.

This is one among the reasons why Xcb was created in the first place: Fix the problems of Xlib. GLX is specified against Xlib so this might seem like a show stopper when it comes to OpenGL. However there is a Xlib wrapping around Xcb and one can safely use that to interface with GLX and still use Xcb for the rest of the program: http://xcb.freedesktop.org/opengl/

I see two possible solutions:

1. Put a `XLockDisplay`/Mutex around `XNextEvent` and the GLX calls each; you don't have to lock for ordinary OpenGL, just the functions prefixed `glX...`.
2. Use Xcb to get runtime correct behaviour and follow the guide I linked above to make it work with OpenGL/GLX.

Comment: I implemented the first solution as a quick fix, but I hope there is a better solution, I'll try the second one.

Answer (score 2):

As eile said you should check that you use XInitThreads.

I was able to get some good results from it when i used a background thread to do the window drawings of an animation. There seems to be no real problem if you stick to drawing code.

If you need more then that and because you are using low level libX11 the best is just to open multiple X11 connections and use one connection per toplevel window. I did this 10 years ago when i played with developing a BeOS cross platform toolkit and when everything was in a worse state then it is now.

You can use this even for event handling and child windows of a toplevel. But this needs some very tricky code for the XEvent masks.

Comment: I'm using XInitThreads, and it isn't enough. And I can't use multiple Display connections, because I can't share GLXContext between them.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing in your render threads? In any case, if you share a Display* connection across different threads you have to call XInitThreads.

I've made good experiences with one Display connection per thread. Use XSelectInput to get events on your main thread. Window IDs are shareable across different Display* connections.

Comment: Speaking for the OP: The OP knows about XInitThreads, see his comment on his question. Opening an additional `Display*` connection is one way to deal with this. Unfortunately it consumes a rare resource: Connections. The X11 servers in its current form unfotunately supports only a rather low number of connections (clients) at a time (something between 256 to 1024); so if each of every process' threads opened a own Display connection you'd run out of connection slots very quickly.

Comment: And multiple Display connections can't have shared GLXContexts - or just I couldn't make them work.

Comment: @Dutow: You can share GLXContexts between different connections only if the contexts involved are indirect rendering contexts, i.e. direct = false calling http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glXCreateContext.xml

Comment: We have one example in the Equalizer distribution (eqAsync) which opens one display connection per GPU and one additional shared context per GPU in a second thread to upload GL textures. Afaik this is using glX - hence my question what you are doing in the second thread. Code is here: https://github.com/Eyescale/Equalizer/tree/master/examples/eqAsync