# Raspberry pi 4 with 2 cam USB

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I’m trying to use this my code in my Raspberry pi but I can only see the image of a camera while on my computer I can already see the image of the two USB cameras someone knows what’s going on, can you help me?

```
import threading

class camThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, previewName, camID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.previewName = previewName
        self.camID = camID
    def run(self):
        print ("Starting " + self.previewName)
        camPreview(self.previewName, self.camID)

def camPreview(previewName, camID):
    cv2.namedWindow(previewName)
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camID)
    if cam.isOpened():  # try to get the first frame
        rval, frame = cam.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        cv2.imshow(previewName, frame)
        rval, frame = cam.read()
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27:  # exit on ESC
            break
    cv2.destroyWindow(previewName)

thread1 = camThread("Camera 1", 0)
thread2 = camThread("Camera 2", 1)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

*shell:*

```
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)

>>> %Run cameraa.py

Starting Camera 1Starting Camera 2

/*error*/
>>> Xlib: charsets ISO8859-1:GR and ISO8859-1:GR have the same CT sequence
Xlib: charsets JISX0201.1976-0:GR and JISX0201.1976-0:GR have the same CT sequence
Xlib: charsets JISX0212.1990-0:GL and JISX0212.1990-0:GL have the same CT sequence
Xlib: charsets CNS11643.1986-1:GR and CNS11643.1986-1:GR have the same CT sequence
Xlib: charsets CNS11643.1992-3:GR and CNS11643.1992-3:GR have the same CT sequence
Xlib: charsets CNS11643.1992-5:GR and CNS11643.1992-5:GR have the same CT sequence
Xlib: charsets CNS11643.1992-7:GR and CNS11643.1992-7:GR have the same CT sequence
Xlib: charsets BIG5-E0:GL and BIG5-E0:GL have the same CT sequence
[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv_build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to concurrently interact with X11 (or any other UI backends as well). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402476/multithreaded-x11-application-and-opengl) for more details.

Specifically for OpenCV, you can check this issue:

> You should interact with UI from the "main" thread only.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8407

Thus, the workaround is using `imshow` and `waitKey` on the main thread only. (instead of over the two threads). In other words, move the three calls (two `imshow`s and one `waitKey`) to the main thread and syncronize the access to the two `Mat` objects you may use to share data between the main thread and the two other threads.